# Performance issue with encrypted AWS RDS instance

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS instance and have created an encrypted copy of this RDS instance. Both the instances are identical except that one is encrypted.

When I executed native SQL queries on these instance, I observed difference in the response time of queries. When the result set contains very large number of records(10000-60000), then encrypted instance performs better. And when the result set container medium number of records(200-500) then the unencrypted RDS instance performs better.

I have another query regarding encryption at REST for RDS - I understand data is stored encrypted. When does it get decrypted - a) when the RDS instance starts,  b) when the connection is created or c) when the query runs d) something else.

Any suggestions or information that can help in understanding above points.

AWS documentation says the performance difference should be negligible, but we see a significant difference in response time.